# How to create URL's like what wordpress does without having a physical page file?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I need to create normal urls like what wordpress does. Ex: https://www.website.ext/mypage
And have them load pages from the database, not just static page files. But like how wordpress and other cms's do.

I'm well aware of the use of url parameters, such as /mypage?ID=124&fname=John
But those are sloppy and can also invite hackers. And I don't want that stuff in my urls if I can avoid it.

How do they have a url to a page that only exists in the database? How do you connect https://www.website.ext/mypage to something that displays in the browser without having an actual "mypage" file and still have these clean urls?

I just can't figure out how it's done. I've messed around a bit with .htaccess things, but I'm not real educated on htaccess stuff.

I suppose I should add that I am working with php7 and MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate it by redirecting traffic on an entry page (for example an `index.php`).
Then do some logic based on the requested URL to render the actual page based on `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` or other url parameters you can use such as the `$_GET` global variable.

You can redirect traffic to a single entry point by using an `.htaccess` such as this on `apache`.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

Options -Indexes
```

I created a personal script that actually do this and if you are interested, you can take a look on it's underlying logic [here](https://github.com/jpneey/basic-php-router) at github.

There are cons on using this such as handling a `404` page request on your own routing.

After being redirected to `index.php` and assuming that your `URL` looks like this `https://sample.com/?page=1`

You can add a `switch case` to render a page based on that variable such as this:

```
<?php

$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 0;

switch($page) {

  case 1:
    require "sample/page/if/one/page.php";
    break;
  case 2:
    require "sample/page/if/two/page.php";
    break;
  default:
    require "default/page/home.php";
    break;
}
```

That is a quick and dirty example but can be greatly improved by creating a router class.
You can also create an array of possible pages and check if the requested page is in that array then render it and if not, display your `404` page.

I am just showing a very minimalist example using the `$_GET` global variable to require some pages but this can also be used to fetch dynamic data from `DB` by utilizing the variable's value.

Comment: I was looking at the wordpress htaccess, looks very similar. So once the page is redirected to index.php, how do I use the information that the htaccess file seems to be  parsing. How do I populate the variables in the index.php page?

Comment: @JKing Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much.
What if my url doesn't have parameters in it like this https://sample.com/?page=1
I'm trying to do it like this https://sample.com/mypage, and have the server know that mypage is the file, and it needs that file name to process in the index.php single entry file. Hope that made sense.
Will this work for page file names that don't have extensions in the url?
Also, will this work for multiple directories?

Comment: Yes if you don't want to rely on `?foo=bar` and use url paths as a variable, you can use them via accessing the `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` global variable

Comment: So do the single point entry method in the htaccess, and then in the index.php, process $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], correct?
I guess I will need to echo $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] first so I can see what it has in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Guys. This site is the best resource on the freaking web for sure.

So here is the solution that is working with the help of you guys in the string. Please tell me if I am missing anything important.

```
.htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
#RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

Options -Indexes
```

This directs any kind of url, without a file extension, to my /dev/index.php page and retains the url in my browser

So `https://www.website.com/dev/dir1/dir2/dir3/page-name-no-ext` displays my /dev/index.php file in the browser while `https://www.website.com/dev/dir1/dir2/dir3/page-name-no-ext` still displays in the web address of my browser. Way cool.

And then in my /dev/index.php page, I collect the results from `$uri = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` to produce `dir1/dir2/dir3/page-name-no-ext`.

This is working nicely with url parameters too with results like `dir1/dir2/dir3/page-name-no-ext?ID=125&user=John`.

From there I can just explode all that, also use GET for any variables that might come through, and tell my /dev/index.php page to load up what it needs. I don't plan on using url parameters though if and when I can help it.

Very nice Guys. Thanks for all your help. Please let me know if my code is missing anything important, or if you see any security issues.

This was my missing piece!

Now I can say goodbye to wordpress. Woo Hoo!

JKing :-)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses (or at least it did when I last saw it) .htaccess files to do what you ask, at least on Apache. I’m not sure what it does if not, I’ve never actually used/installed Wordpress.

Here’s another take on using a .htaccess file to do what you’re talking about:

First we look for (after the main domain, i.e. yoursite.com) /page1 or /page2, etc. I added an example for a subpage too, so it also looks for /page4/subpage1 (or page4/subpage2). It takes any requests to those pages and reroutes them (internally, so the visitor’s browser doesn’t see it) to index.php.

`RewriteRule ^(?:page1|page2|page3|page4[?:/subpage1|subpage2]?|page5)/?$ index.php [L]`

This looks for requests for index.php

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index\.php$`

Then we look at the redirect status of all requests to index.php.

`RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^4(0[0-9]|1[0-7]|2[2-4,6])|5(0[0-7]|10)$`

If it’s not any of those statuses (please please don’t ask me how to figure out how I got that again), we assume someone is trying to open the main script, so we pretend that it’s not there. Really we’re just telling Apache to lie to the browser, and give a 404 page to our site.

`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http:\\yoursite.com\404.html [R=404,L]`

Then we also look for people requesting the pages directly, like yoursite.com/page2.php, and we give them a 404 error for that, because you want the pretty links, not the ugly ones. If you already have a website with the pages there, you would use a 301 (moved permanently) so you don’t break the old links, and send the requests to your main script also (instead of your 404 page).

`RewriteRule ^ -(?: page1|page2|page3|page4[?:/subpage1|subpage2]?|page5) \.php/? $ http://yoursite.com/404.html [R=404,L]`

And I like to put this at the very bottom of .htaccess files. It’s supposed to stop you from creating .htaccess loops. But always put it at the very bottom of your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

We don’t even need to pass any variables to index.php, because in index.php we use

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

to read the original requested address. Then we can pick the page the user wants and load it.

Why go to all this trouble? Because this method only reroutes page requests to the pages that already exist, which puts a lot less load on the server than rerouting every request to the main script. It also forces people to use the addresses you want to visit your site, and prevents your main page from showing up under ‘phantom addresses’ and multiple addresses. Not passing any variables to the php script also makes the regexes run faster.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to add every page to the page regexes (the ones with page1, page2, etc.) or this won’t work. So if it’s a website with a ton of pages it won’t be effective to write them all in manually. It is possible to write a script to edit the file for you, but if you have a large number of pages it will be difficult to manage manually in that case anyway.

Edit: I see that your main script is index.php so I updated what I wrote to reflect that. Also note that what I wrote will not allow people to open index.php directly, but it does recognize just your main site address without any pages.